# DbConnection cannot be constructed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I'm facing a weird exception that is given below while trying to use unity.

"The type DbConnection cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value"

First of all I've googled this one but couldn't find any such exception detail. Its bin for a while now I'm trying to debug it so can anyone guide me here.

Updated: my container configurations

```
        var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CaresDbEntities"].ConnectionString;

        var container = new UnityContainer();            
        container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);  

        #region new repository n UnitOfwork configuration
        container
            .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>))
            .RegisterType(typeof(IService<>), typeof(CrudService<>))   //yet to be tested
            .RegisterType<CaresDbEntities>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString))
            .RegisterType<DbContext, CaresDbEntities>()
            .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, CaresDbEntities>();


        #endregion


        container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
        container.RegisterType<IRoleService, RoleService>();
        container.RegisterType<IMenuService, MenuService>();
        container.RegisterType<IUserFunctionService, UserFunctionService>();
        container.RegisterType<IFormsAuthentication, FormAuthenticationService>();

        var testContainter = container.Resolve<DbContext>();
        var testService1 = container.Resolve<IFormsAuthentication>();
        var testService2 = container.Resolve<IUserService>();
        var testService3 = container.Resolve<IMenuService>();
```

This exception appears in the 3rd and 4th line of code. thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a variable named DbConnection? if so, which type is it?

Comment: I dont have any such variable.

Comment: Is there an InnerException?  It sounds like one of the objects has a dependency on DbConnection somewhere in the constructor dependency tree.

Comment: @Tuzo that was the inner exception i pasted in my question. Main message was something like dependencies resolution failed with unity.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the concrete implementation of `IUserService` and/or `IMenuService` require a concrete `DbConnection` in their constructor OR a dependeny of those needs it. So please recheck your constructor **carefully** and if you really need to use `DbConnection` you'll have to register it in container.

Comment: you're right I've setup all the required dependencies. the same code is working just fine with other solutions. DbContext is the only place which mainly requires DbConnection I suppose. And as you can see that is being resolved without any problem. I still don't get why this is happening to me appearently there is no DbConnection under any services however IServices do operate on a generic repository and repository is causing the same error while i try to resolve it again no DbConnection in its constructor either. Any clue

Comment: What other solutions do work? Do you mean other IoC frameworks? Please also show the registration of DbContext, IUserService and IMenuService by editing your question.

Comment: here is the weird stuff, as you can see I'm using EF 4.2. I've a DAL project that implements generic repository. Its all work fine with it. problem is I've to plugin my projects to the main framework code base DAL which is apparently same code files as i've compared them all but it doesn't seem to be compatible something weird is going on .

Comment: I updated my question and other solution is the same DAL project with different namespaces mainly as far as I can tell. We thought of using single DAL for multiple solutions so had to get it on a centralized code base across all solutions.